# What is meaning of 'nanny state' conversation in S05E11

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, breaking-bad

In S05E11 of *Breaking Bad*, a scene made me think of something. 
In the restroom a guy complained:

> Nanny state. When I see a kid with his bicycle helmet on, I want to
>   smack the shit out of him, like for his own good.

While the other man wiping blood of their shoes. It’s a charming little scene.

I don't understand the meaning of this scene. Is it sarcasm that the guy is like a nanny? Or sarcasm that modern American culture is like a nanny?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[A transcript I found online](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=165&t=10101) shows the full quote. It has

> Ever been on a plane and find yourself looking down at the armrest
>   next to you, looking at the little plug where the ashtray used to go?
>   I look at that and I say, "What the hell happened to this country?"
>   Nanny state.
>
> I see a kid with a bicycle helmet on, I wanna smack the sh1t out of
>   him. Like, for his own good.

[Nanny state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanny_state) is a set phrase that is (per wikipedia)

> a term of British origin that conveys a view that a government or its
>   policies are overprotective or interfering unduly with personal
>   choice. The term "nanny state" likens government to the role that a
>   nanny has in child rearing.

The first line is decrying this behaviour, for example increasing prohibitions on smoking. The second line adds the example of a child with a bicycle helmet on; bicycle helmets are another thing intended to make life safer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What is meaning of 'other man wiping blood of their shoes' in this scene? Is it a sarcasm?

Comment: @卢声远ShengyuanLu sorry, I haven't actually seen the show past season 1, so I can't help you with that